Handle occasional left-right swaps
I'm running a model that estimates pose from a video. When the person is seen from the side, left and right side are occasionally swapped.
I'm trying to find a simple method to handle this, maybe by combining both left and right points to make the series side agnostic, and then running something to filter/cluster/separate both signal and assign a side to each point.
I would be surprised if no such thing existed but I'm drawing a blank. I'd appreciate your help, thanks!


Bumping up just a little in case some helpful people missed it :)
